# Insert multiple rows using one statement vs batch insert in mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Which one will give me better performance?

1. Use Java simply loop the value and added to the sql string and execute the statement at once? Note that PreparedStatement is also used.

   `INSERT INTO tbl (   c1 ,    c2 ,    c3 )
      VALUES ('r1c1', 'r1c2', 'r1c3'),
      ('r2c1', 'r2c2', 'r2c3'),
      ('r3c1', 'r3c2', 'r3c3')`
2. Use the batch execution as below.

   `String SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO tbl (c1, c2, c3) VALUES (?, ?, ?);";`

   ```
   try (
           Connection connection = database.getConnection();
           PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT);
       ) {

       int i = 0;
       for (Entity entity : entities) {
           statement.setString(1, entity.getSomeProperty());
           // ...

           statement.addBatch();
           i++;

           if (i % 1000 == 0 || i == entities.size()) {
               statement.executeBatch(); // Execute every 1000 items.
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Benchmark and find out. You'll need to find an optimal batch size. Too large and you waste time preparing. Too small and you run too many queries.

Comment: Yeah i agree with @tadman, you should test and find out empirically for yourself. I will say I think Batch Statements were made for this exact reason.

Comment: Sometimes the performance of a prepared statement is surprising. They're intended to be re-used like this.

Comment: I might misunderstand your answers, guys. But I am not talking about the optimal batch size for 2nd way. I am thinking about if both way used PreparedStatement to execute. Which way perform better? Assume there are about 10k to 60k rows to be inserted

Comment: Also look to see if there is a 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE' api in java to programaticly inject data as if it was a CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

I did a presentation a few years ago I called [Load Data Fast!](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/load-data-fast). I compared many different methods of inserting data as fast as possible, and benchmarked them.

[LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/load-data.html) was much faster than any other method.

But there are other factors that affect the speed, like the type of data, and the type of hardware, and perhaps the load on the system from other concurrent clients of the database. The results I got only describe what the performance is on a Macbook Pro.

Ultimately, you need to test your specific case on your server to get the most accurate answer.

This is what being a software engineer is about. You don't always get the answers spoon-fed to you. You have to do some testing to confirm them.

Comment: Will try to test and see. Thanks.